# Blender 4.0 OSL x Bevel shader Problem

Tags: bevel, osl

There is a problem with Blender 4.0. Whenever I turn on 'OSL shading language' option and use Beven shader, object goes dark. Here's screenshots. Is this a bug? or am I doing something wrong?
The thing is that I need OSL in this project :(
Anyone aware of this problem?
Thank you in advance.
[image]